# What's wrong with my (Conway's Game Of) life?

Tags: java, algorithm, processing, cellular-automata

I tried to write an OOP implementation of Conway's Game of Life in processing. However, it seems to be some other sort of automaton. Interesting, but not what I was going for. I can't find any problems with my code, that's what I'm hoping you can help with.

```
    class Cell {
    int state;
    int x;
    int y;

    Cell update()
  {
    try {

      int neighbors = 0;
      for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
          neighbors += currentBoard[x+i][y+j].state;
        }
      }
      if      ((state == 1) && (neighbors <  2))return new Cell(x, y, 0);
      else if ((state == 1) && (neighbors >  3))return new Cell(x, y, 0); 
      else if ((state == 0) && (neighbors == 3))return new Cell(x, y, 1); 
      else return new Cell(x, y, state);
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
      return new Cell(x, y, 0);
    }
  }

  Cell( int _x, int _y, int _s)
  {
    state = _s;
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
  }
}

Cell[][] currentBoard;
Cell[][] newBoard;

void setup() {
  fullScreen();
  //frameRate(100);
  currentBoard = new Cell[width][height];
  newBoard = new Cell[width][height];
  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
      currentBoard[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, int(random(2)));
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  print(frameCount);
  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
      try {
        newBoard[i][j] = currentBoard[i][j].update();
      }
      catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
      }
    }
  }


  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
      color setCol = color(255, 0, 0);
      if (newBoard[i][j].state == 1)
      {
        setCol = color(0, 0, 0);
      } else if (newBoard[i][j].state == 0)
      {
        setCol = color(255, 255, 255);
      }


      set(i, j, setCol);
    }
  }
  currentBoard = newBoard;
}
```

What's wrong? Also, any information on the automaton I accidentally created would be cool, it creates some beautiful patterns.

Comment: At a glance, it looks like you're counting a cell as one of its own neighbors.

Comment: You're going to have to [debug your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to narrow it down to a line of code that's behaving differently from what you expected.

Comment: What's wrong?  You tell us.  What did you expect?  What does the program actually do?  What is the difference?

Comment: `However, it seems to be some other sort of automaton. Interesting, but not what I was going for.` What exactly does this mean? What are you expecting, and how is different from what you're observing?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 That was just a comment on what actually happened. It's some other sort of automaton. Run the code, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @domojz: To become a software professional, you need to better describe and quantify your bugs. Saying "it looks like something else" will not get you very far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at this section of your code:

```
try {

  int neighbors = 0;
  for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
      neighbors += currentBoard[x+i][y+j].state;
    }
  }
  if      ((state == 1) && (neighbors <  2))return new Cell(x, y, 0);
  else if ((state == 1) && (neighbors >  3))return new Cell(x, y, 0); 
  else if ((state == 0) && (neighbors == 3))return new Cell(x, y, 1); 
  else return new Cell(x, y, state);
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
  return new Cell(x, y, 0);
}
```

There are a couple things that seem wrong here. First, what happens when both `i` and `j` are `0`? You're going to count each cell as its own neighbor, which is not correct.

Secondly, what happens if you're on an edge? You're going to encounter an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and return a dead cell. Again, this is probably not what you want to do. Silent catch blocks like this are a recipe for bugs that you don't detect until you see unexplained behavior.

Taking a step back, you really need to get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging). You could have figured out all of the above by creating a smaller example (say, a 3x3 grid of cells) and stepping through it with a piece of paper and a pencil, or the debugger that comes with the Processing editor. This should always be the first thing you do.

Comment: The cell's counting of itself was the issue, thank you! The returning the dead cell is what I meant to do, just a way to handle the edge case instead of looping.

Comment: @domojz Why would you have to loop? Just ad an `if` statement that checks whether `i` and `j` are both in-bounds before checking.